# Not getting right out put by if else condition in java script

Tags: javascript, html

i am new in javascript and using same logic and logical operator in java script but Not getting right output by if else condition in javascript it giving same output in all condition

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>


var x = document.getElementById["a"].value;
var y = document.getElementById["b"].value;

function compare()
{
  if(x>y) {
    alert ("x is greater");
  } else if(x == y) {
    alert ("both are equals");
  } else {
    alert("y is greater")
  }
}


</script>
</head>

<body>

<form onsubmit="compare()" >
x---><input type="text" id="a"><br>
y---><input type="text" id="b"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Multiple issues from bad syntax, to comparing strings (not numbers), to reading the values before the inputs are even created. Use your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grab the values of the input boxes inside your compare function.

Here's how to do it:

```html
<script>
  function compare() {

    var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("b").value;

    if (x > y) {
      alert("x is greater");
    } else if (x == y) {
      alert("both are equals");
    } else {
      alert("y is greater")
    }
  }
</script>

<form onsubmit="compare()">
  x--->
  <input type="text" id="a">
  <br>y--->
  <input type="text" id="b">
  <br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are retrieving the values before the document (DOM) is ready. To fix this retrieve the values from within the `compare` function.

```js
function compare() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
  if (x > y)
    alert("x is greater");
  else if (x == y)
    alert("both are equals");
  else
    alert("y is greater");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="compare()">
  x---><input type="text" id="a"><br>
  y---><input type="text" id="b"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Oops thats becase I copy and pasted the question and assumed they used parentisis

Answer (score 0):

The variable x and y are declared outside of the function so they are initialized when page run first time. so both have null value.

You have to add them inside function like

```
function compare() {

   var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
   var y = document.getElementById("b").value;
   //Check your conditions here
}
```